# Проверка строки на наличие букв

Tags: c#

Как проверить строку на наличие букв более коротким способом, чем просто перебор и огромное условие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это решается просто с помощью регулярных выражений

```
Regex.IsMatch(test, "^[^x]+$");
```

- `test` - строка для проверки
- `^` - начало строки
- `[^x]` - все символы, кроме символа `x`
- `+` - одно или более вхождений
- `$` - конец строки

В итоге строка будет проверена на наличие буквы `x`.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (str.Any(c => char.IsLetter(c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

берем первый символ, если он равен 0, неОК, если 1 - неОК и тд =), если А - ОК -  это длинный?

```
char.isLetter();
```